# Losing scope of click 'event' within ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, scope, click

I need help trying to stop a save event from happening based on a result from the Database via ajax.  However I seem to be losing the scope of my "event" variable and I'm not sure how to keep it.  Your help is much appreciated.

Function based on click of the save button:

```
jQuery('#saveButton').on('click',function(){
    checkForOpenActions(event)});
```

Ajax call:

```
function checkForOpenActions(event) {
  // determine if case has any case actions that are not resolved.
  if (jQuery('#PboCaseResolution_caseAction').val() != '') {
    jQuery.getJSON("page.request.do?page=com.blah.ajax", {
        trackingId: '$!parentId'
      },
      function(data) {
        alert("data: " + data);
        if (data == 1) {
          alert("data is 1");
          if (confirm('There are open actions on this case.  Are you sure you want to close it?')) {
            return true;
          } else {
            stopSave(event);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Call from Ajax to stop the save:

```
function stopSave(event){
    alert("preventing Default");
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You cannot reliably stop the event after the ajax has finished.  Ajax is asynchronous.  This means the logic could have easily progressed pass where you are and finished all the logic associated with that event before the ajax finishes and you try to terminate the event.

Comment: Instead of trying to stop the event, consider flipping your logic.  Always stop the save.  Then, only if you get a good response from the ajax, then make that start the save logic.

Comment: @Taplar - My problem is waiting for the Ajax to finish. I'm not sure how to only evaluate after the ajax function has returned with the result.

Comment: @JimBell You put the logic into the AJAX callback function. So instead of `return true`, you call a function that performs the save.

Comment: @Barmar Thats what I want to do but I lose scope of the event when I enter the AJAX function.

Comment: Pass variables with the details as arguments to `checkForOpenActions()`.

Comment: BTW, `event` is not a global variable. You should write `jQuery('#saveButton').on('click',function(event){`

Comment: @Barmar Isn't that what I'm doing already by passing the 'event'?

Comment: You're not using any of the properties of `event`.

Comment: What in `event` contains the information that you want to save?

Comment: @Barmar I have no idea.  I'm totally lost.  I just want to stop the save button from executing when the user does not confirm the dialog box.

Comment: As the above comments said, you have to reverse the logic when you're using AJAX. You call `preventDefault` all the time. Then when the user confirms the action, you perform the save in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're performing the confirmation in the AJAX callback function, it runs asynchronously, so you can't use `event.preventDefault()` there -- the original event handler has already returned.

You need to call `event.preventDefault()` unconditionally, and then do the save explicitly in the callback function when the user confirms. You can call `submit()` on the form containing the button to do that.

```
jQuery('#saveButton').on('click', function(event) {
  checkForOpenActions(event);
});


function checkForOpenActions(event) {
  // determine if case has any case actions that are not resolved.
  if (jQuery('#PboCaseResolution_caseAction').val() != '') {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.getJSON("page.request.do?page=com.blah.ajax", {
        trackingId: '$!parentId'
      },
      function(data) {
        alert("data: " + data);
        if (data == 1) {
          alert("data is 1");
          if (!confirm('There are open actions on this case.  Are you sure you want to close it?')) {
            return;
          }
        }
        event.target.form.submit();
      });
  }
}
```